# Is it appropriate to ask questions on how to boost the reception on my FM radio here?

Tags: discussion

I know that this stack exchange is mean for amateur radio. Would it still be acceptable to ask about issues with the antenna and reception of my FM radio here, or is there a better place for that?

Answer (score 1):

My initial reaction is, "Why not phrase the question in an amateur radio context?"  For example:

> I am receiving an FM modulated VHF signal with my radio and I'm wondering what options there are for boosting the signal that I am receiving.  Can I amplify the signal from the antenna?  Is there a specific type of antenna or orientation of the antenna that will work best?  Can these be broken down based on the distance from the transmitter?

Comment: yep. "Questions about the technology of radio" are clearly on-topic. I do like to add that the answers you might be getting can be more technical than you would like them to be, if you were hoping for a consumer electronics solution.

Comment: Since it's clearly on-topic... why does it need to be reworded at all? I'd love to see us figure out how to lean toward acceptance rather than exclusion.

Comment: Hmm.. My gut reaction is that someone asking about boosting reception to their FM radio is an amateur asking about a radio, but not someone asking about amateur radio... Not sure if the distinction matters.  Let's see if anyone else pipes up in meta.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer I kind of see your logic, but I don't think it matters. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It certainly is, because it's about the *technology of radio*.

You might try searching to see if a similar question has been asked and answered. If not, then by all means go ahead and ask! :-)